# Complex Line Integral Limits

Tags: complex-integration

Let $\gamma$ be the circle in the complex plane given by $|z-i| = 1$, with counterclockwise orientation. Evaluate $$\int \frac{|z|^2}{(z-i)^2} dz$$

The function $|z|^2$ is not analytic. How would I set up the limits for this integral, is it just 0 to $2\pi$ because its a circle?

Comment: How do you want to parametrize the circle?  This must be answered before you can even ask about the limits.

Comment: It's $$\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{|i+re^{it}|^2}{r^2e^{2rit}}ire^{it}\,dt$$ using the obvious parametrisation.

Comment: I know for a circle its x(t) = rcost and y(t) = rsint, but I'm not sure how to apply that for this case. Could you explain how you got that integral?

Comment: Only a circle *centered at the origin* can be parametrized by $x = r\cos t, y = r\sin t$. This circle is centered at $i\ (x = 0, y = 1)$, not $0$.